Crystal Report Viewer Alternative
Hello all I know this is mostly a problem solving forum but I want to ask for some opinions. We have used Crystal Reports for sometime and our users are asking for more reports that require interactions. Passing of simple parameters like what village, or country etc nothing complex so they don't need to be report writers just need to view reports and change simple prompts. I downloaded CR Viewer and tough I could accomplish this but when I open the report in CR Viewer the prompts are still static. I reached out to support and was informed we would need to purchase CR Server. CR Server is rather expensive. I was wondering what would be a good alternative to CR Viewer? I have taken a look at Logicity but wanted to reach out to people who may have experience with this. Thanks

Have you considered a BI tool instead of a reporting tool?  Good BI tool/platform can easily cost as much as CR Server or more, but there are ways to do it for free using just Excel and an ODBC connection and some very simple SQL scripts.  While this may not be the solution you need right now, its something you should consider as a way to enhance the business for the future.
